# How can I print out the current keybindings in Linux/Debian?

Tags: keyboard, console, tty

How can I print out the current keybindings in Linux/Debian ? I tried

```
xmodmap -pp
```

and got the response:

```
xmodmap:  unable to open display ''
```

Comment: What keybindings? You seem to want to do this from a system with no X, if so, please mention that in your question.

Comment: Try `dumpkeys`...

Comment: @yeti dumpkeys results in 'Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console'

Comment: You've set a tag `console`, so I thought you'd search the command to dump the console keymap. The easiest way is to run it on the real text console or use `dumpkeys </dev/console`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two different keymaps. One used by your graphical environment (X) and one used by you console.

The first one is configured by `xmodmap` and `setxkbmap`. The second one is configured by `loadkeys`.

You can dump the first one with `xmodmap` and the second one with `dumpkeys`.

Have a look at the man pages of those commands to find the correct options and other related commands.

Comment: `dumpkeys` results in `Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console`; `xmodmap` results in `xmodmap:  unable to open display ''`

Comment: `dumpkeys` works only on the console. `xmodmap` works only from a terminal emulator in X. Where do you enter your command?

Comment: Right now I am using SSH through PuTTy; other times I use Linux virtual consoles.

Comment: SSH through PuTTy is using the normal windows mapping. What exactly do you mean with "virtual consoles"?

Comment: what do you mean by "normal windows mapping"? I want to find out what character sequences/bytes are being sent to the console when I am typing in PuTTy, for example, how can I do that? Virtual consoles in Linux are the default terminals that the OS creates on startup. They are accessed by pressing Alt+F1-6 (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console) for more information.

Comment: Those virtual consoles are exactly those that use `loadkeys` and `dumpkeys`. The bytes sent by PuTTy are usually just the character pressed. For some special keys you can configure the bytes in the PuTTy configuration.

Comment: @TylerDurden Try `sudo dumpkeys`